# how to reduce a list of tuples, return a concrete number

Tags: python

I was wondering what is wrong with my code, it now has a **typeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable**

```
# this function is to calculate Weighted Average Maturity of the mortgage pool
# pass in a list of mortgages (amount, rate, terms)
def WAM(tup):
    return reduce(WAM_SUM, tup)


def WAM_SUM(x, y):
    return (x[0] * (x[2]/12) + y[0] * (y[2]/12)) / (x[0] + y[0])
```

the list of tuple will be passing in is something like this (first one is amount, and the third one is term):
[(208000, 0.015, 120), (156000, 0.03, 180), (720000, 0.065, 240), (333000, 0.087, 120), (241000, 0.0315, 240)]

I would like to use reduce to make it plays the same functionality as below:

```
def weightedAM(tup):
    sum_val = sum(amount for amount, rate, term in tup)  #sum up all the loan amount
    wam_sum = sum((amount / sum_val) * (term / 12) for amount, rate, term in tup)
    return wam_sum
```

Comment: You need to remember that `reduce` essentially doing `func( func( func( x, y), y), y)`.  Your function expects two tuples and returns a single float.  How do you expect to feed that float back into `WAM_SUM`?  `reduce` is just the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: In general, `reduce` (or `fold`, in some languages) **always** requires a closed binary operator on some type `T` because the output of the first function call is passed to the next function call. If the function returns something that is *not* `T`, then the function cannot operate on it! Some examples of closed binary operators: `+` on `int`, `str`, and `list` (right? The `+` takes two operands of one of those types and returns a value of the same type -- take some time to convince yourself of this fact).

Comment: Thank you, I carefully look at reduce and figure a way out. instead of using one reduce, I use two to address my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing one reduce, I would do two now, and it works

```
def WAM(tup):
    return reduce(WAM_SUM, tup, 0) / reduce(Amount_SUM, tup, 0)


def WAM_SUM(total, tup):
    return total + (tup[0] * (tup[2] / 12))


def Amount_SUM(total, tup):
    return total + tup[0]
```

also I could use lambda:

```
def WAM_L(tup):
    return reduce(lambda total, WAM_SUM1: total + (WAM_SUM1[0] * (WAM_SUM1[2] / 12)), tup, 0) / \
           reduce(lambda total, Amount_SUM1: total + Amount_SUM1[0], tup, 0)
```

However, in terms of code clarity and readability, I do think the original one is better than reduce